# simpler theme/view mechanism/function?

Tags: views, theming

Is there a module that provide a base/framework for simpler/faster rendering of a view(in MVC terms).. a function like

> render_tpl('path/to/my/tpl/myview.tpl, array('var1'=>$var1,
>   'var2'=>$var2);

? 
You see something much simpler than having to declare my theme to the theme registry via hook_theme etc... (sometimes it seems overkill just to render a simple layout)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do that using existing Drupal modules or functions. If you really want to do something alternative, look into guidelines/recipes for creating own functions for simple templating parsing. However, I honestly don't see any reason for doing it.

Comment: don't you feel that it is sometimes overkill/tedious just to theme something very simple with hook_theme etc...? when I work with other frameworks, it is so much simpler with something like $this->view('mypage.tpl', array('title'=>'hello world');

Comment: I know the theme system of drupal is very flexible allowing to theme and override every single element being rendered but sometimes it feels too "heavy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There wasn't enough space in the comment field, so I'll write a full answer :)

As far as I know, there is no way to do that using existing Drupal modules or functions. If you really want to do something alternative, look into guidelines/recipes for creating own functions for simple templating parsing.

> don't you feel that it is sometimes overkill/tedious just to theme something very simple with hook_theme etc...?

With the same logic, you could argue that you don't need any `hook_menu()` implementations, and that all you could do is have a `.php` file in the root of the site from where you would query the database directly :)

It all boils down to conventions because they imply more efficient/simpler maintenance, security, self-explanatory code for other people working on the same project, etc.

However, if you are the only one who is responsible for the site, you're free to do whatever works.

P. S. Toying around and stripping Drupal/turning it into something else can be very good for learning how things work at the higher level. Few years ago I maintained an in-house stripped version of Drupal 5 and 6 for own purposes, with different folder structure, without many modules/features I did not need and some other tweaks. It was a great learning experience.

Comment: I find hook_menu useful... you already need routing paths for clean urls so it is quite useful to have a "routes" registry...but for themes... I find it too bulky to have a theme registry.

Comment: I am very tempted in building my own template engine for my module...

Comment: Then there's nothing to stop you :) there are plenty of resources for small template parsing classes and functions. Heck, if you don't need loops or any similar features, you could even just use `strtr()` and use pseudo code to define variables, like mustache.

Comment: yup i am still evaluating the pros and cons lol ... I am examining drupal bootstrap process and how it renders the pages ... lol interesting (how did the drupal creators coded such a beast!)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to render a template, without defining any theme function, then you could simply use [`theme_render_template()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_render_template/7).

I would rather go with `hook_theme()`, but to just render a template file, that is the simpler code you could use. `theme()` itself uses that function.

```
// Default render function and extension.
$render_function = 'theme_render_template';
$extension = '.tpl.php';

// The theme engine may use a different extension and a different renderer.
global $theme_engine;
if (isset($theme_engine)) {
  if ($info['type'] != 'module') {
    if (function_exists($theme_engine . '_render_template')) {
      $render_function = $theme_engine . '_render_template';
    }
    $extension_function = $theme_engine . '_extension';
    if (function_exists($extension_function)) {
      $extension = $extension_function();
    }
  }
}

// ...

if (!isset($variables['directory'])) {
  $default_template_variables = array();
  template_preprocess($default_template_variables, $hook);
  $variables += $default_template_variables;
}

// Render the output using the template file.
$template_file = $info['template'] . $extension;
if (isset($info['path'])) {
  $template_file = $info['path'] . '/' . $template_file;
}
$output = $render_function($template_file, $variables);
```

You could use similar code for your case, and your code would work even if you change theme engine for the template files you write: instead of the global `$theme_engine`, use another way to set the theme engine to use for those templates.

Keep in mind that code would not work on Drupal 8. Since code for Drupal 8 is going to change, anyway, this is should not be a problem.

Comment: theme_render_template() seems to be the function I was searching for! it's very simple :) i don't quite understand what you mean if I change theme engine?

if i use something like this: theme_render_template('hellomyview', array("title"=>$node->title); this won't work if i change theme engine?

Comment: It works with the PHPTemplate engine; if you were using another theme engine, you need to use the more generic code, which is the one used by `theme()`. If you know you will be using just the PHPTemplate engine, the default one, then simply call `theme_render_template()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling views in your system why you are not trying it with angularJS.

Module available in drupal.org https://drupal.org/project/angularjs or you can use it directly with using xml feeds too.

Otherwise use view content cache is a simpler modules to use and load cached views faster
https://drupal.org/project/views_content_cache

Hope it helps